# When do .so files get loaded Linux?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlopen, dynamic-loading

I have a shared object (a.so) which is linked to my executable myexe. 
a.so exposed a method called get_val(), which myexe is using.

Now when a.so will be loaded into myexe's process address space? is it when myexe calls get_val() API, or when myexe gets launched.

Comment: It is operating system specific. Are you on Linux?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot mention.Yes I am asking this for linux OS

Comment: One question per post please. I've removed Q2 and Q3, use the Ask Question link to make 2 new posts, one per each question.

Comment: but that 3 other Qs are very much related and coupled, which needs to be asked in this context only.
I didn't understand why you suddenly remove it and gave me minus -1 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two (three) types of libraries:

- *static libraries* (suffix: `.a` / `.lib`), which itself becomes part of the binary. Strictly speaking, it's not the whole library, it's those objects from the library which are required to satisfy unresolved links.
- *shared (dynamic) libraries* (suffix: `.so` / `.dll`), which come in two flavors, distinguished by the time the library is loaded:

  - *dynamic link library*, which are libraries of which you told the compiler and linker and which you call like static libraries but which are not part of your library - they are loaded by the loader/linker (in Linux usually as part of `__main()` from `libc` by calling `dlopen()`).
  - *dynamic load library* for which you call `dlopen()` yourself.

(The terms seem a bit fuzzy, I've seen different literature using different terms; the terms above is how I memorized it in order to remember the concepts.)

So, if you use `a.so` without calling `dlopen()` yourself, `a.so` is a dynamic link library, so it is loaded at program start. In that case, removing `a.so` from the system will prevent your program from starting - it will be loaded, but it will fail before `main()` gets called.

If you use `a.so` with calling `dlopen()` yourself, it's completely under your control.

On your questions

Q1: If you call `dlopen()` yourself, with `RTLD_LAZY`, the `a.so` will be loaded when the first unresolved call that can be resolved by `a.so` is made. If you call `dlopen()` yourself, with `RTLD_NOW`, `a.so` is loaded immediately, i.e. before `dlopen()` returns. If you do not call `dlopen()` yourself but let `libc` do the work for you, `a.so` will be loaded at program start.

Q2: You delete `a.so`. If you call `dlopen()` with `RTLD_LAZY`, and do not run through the code that needs `a.so`, the program will run happily, otherwise a signal will be raised. If you do not call `dlopen()` but let `libc` do the work for you, the program will not start successfully.

Q3: Effectively, there is no way to load `a.so` without calling `dlopen()` (or something equivalent that would replace it). The question is just, do you call `dlopen()` yourself, or do you let the environment (i.e. `libc`) do the work for you.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not an expert for this stuff, and some parts of my answer may be wrong. I'll verify those parts of my answer on which I have doubts myself, i.e. whether it is `libc` that calls `dlopen()` or something else, and whether or not it's possible to have lazy binding even if you're not using `dlopen()` yourself. I'll update the answer once I have the results.

Comment: thanks a lot. You almost answered all my doubts. Just for readers I am pasting my question here as Admin has deleted my half portions of questions.

Q1. Now when a.so will be loaded into myexe's process address space? 
is it when myexe calls get_val() API, or when myexe gets launched.
Q2. And now assume a condition where myexe don't call that API get_val at all, under this condition if I delete a.so from "/usr/lib" and try to launch myexe, will myexe get launch?
Q3. Is there any way to load a.so, with out calling dlopen(a.so)? please explain when we do we need to call dlopen to load a library?

Comment: Hi Christian, One more doubt: how to make a.so library as dymanic link libray so that libc will take care of loading it at program starts...

Comment: Many of the details of this answer, e.g. when exactly `a.so` is loaded, or the difference between `RTLD_LAZY` and `RTLD_NOW`, are completely wrong.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I almost feared so, hence the Disclaimer. But if you know they're wrong, you probably know what's right instead, so why don't you just share this with us in comments, or even better, an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are on Linux/x86-64. It is OS specific.

Generally, the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared library is loaded at start of execution time, by [ld-linux.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.so.8.html). Practically, the shared library should be [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (PIC).

But it could depend, and there is [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) with its flag `RTLD_NOW` or `RTLD_LAZY`

Read [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and the [x86-64 ABI specification](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi-0.99.pdf)

You could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find out what is happening on your own Linux system.

You could in principle dynamically load a `foo.so` by using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and processing by yourself the [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29). I've done (nearly) that in the previous century (for SPARC), and believe me it is a tedious task.

BTW, `dlopen` is implemented in [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and in [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/). Both are free software, you could study their source code.

Read also the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/). It explains some details, briefly speaking:

- compile the source files of the shared object as PIC using

  ```
   gcc -Wall -fPIC -O src1.c -o src1.pic.o
   gcc -Wall -fPIC -O src2.c -o src2.pic.o
  ```
- link them in a shared library `foo.so` using

  ```
   gcc -shared src1.pic.o src2.pic.o -o foo.so
  ```
- use a full path to `dlopen`, e.g

  ```
       void* dlh = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_NOW);
       if (!dlh) { fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  ```

Then you could have a convention saying that your `foo.so` plugin should have a function of signature

```
  typedef int sayhello_sig_t(const char*);
```

that is named `say_hello` and you get its address using:

```
  sayhello_sig_t* funptr = dlsym(dlh, "say_hello");
  if (!funptr) { 
     fprintf(stderr, 
             "dlsym say_hello failure: %s\n, dlerror();
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```