# Symbol lookup error at runtime instead of load time

Tags: c++, linux, ld

I have an application which uses a class Foo from an .so shared library. I've come across a problem where at runtime it prints

> <appname>: symbol lookup error: <appname>: undefined symbol: <mangled_Foo_symbol_name>

Now, it turned out that the unmangled symbol was for the constructor of the class Foo, and the problem was simply that an old version of the library was loaded, which didn't contain Foo yet.

My question isn't about resolving the error (that's obviously to use the correct library), but why it appears **at runtime** instead of at time of load / startup.

The line of code causing the error just instantiates an object of class Foo, so I'm not using anything like dlopen here, at least not explicitly / to my knowledge.

In contrast, if I remove the whole library from the load search path, I get this error **at startup**:

> <appname>: error while loading shared libraries: libname.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When the wrong version of gcc / libstdc++ is on the load path, an error also appears at starup:

> <appname>: /path/to/gcc-4.8.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by <appname>)

---

This "fail fast" behavior is much more desirable, I don't want to run my application for quite awhile first, until I finally realize it's using the wrong library.
What causes the load error to appear at runtime and how can I make it appear immediately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do .so files get loaded Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285546/when-do-so-files-get-loaded-linux)

Comment: I think this not duplicate as he is asking way to force all relocations at compile time instead asking about linking details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page of `ld.so`:

> #### ENVIRONMENT
>
> - `LD_BIND_NOW` (libc5;  glibc  since  2.1.1)  If set to a nonempty string, causes the dynamic linker to resolve all symbols at program startup instead of deferring function call resolution to the point when they are first referenced. This is useful when using a debugger.
> - `LD_WARN` (ELF only)(glibc since 2.1.3) If set to a nonempty string, warn about unresolved symbols.

Comment: LD_BIND_NOW works like a charm, gives a symbol lookup error immediately.
LD_WARN doesn't seem to produce any additional output. I thought it would produce a warning at startup and then run until the error is encountered, but the behavior is identical to before.

Is there a linker flag or similar to enforce the LD_BIND_NOW behavior without setting the environment variable?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know whether there is a linker flag or similar to enforce the LD_BIND_NOW behaviour - that may well be worth a new question of its own.

Comment: See also [answer mentioning `-z now` linker flag](/a/22954926/4850040).  It's not quite the same thing, but may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not statically link `.so` library. If you want to avoid load/run time errors you have to use all static libraries (`.a`). If you do not have static version of library and source then try to find some *statifier*. After googling I find few statifiers but do not know how do they work so leaving that part up to you.

Comment: As seen in my question, libstdc++.so is also linked dynamically but I get the lookup error at load time, not runtime.

Comment: I think libc is an exception. It is unlikely to see this behavior with other SO